# Floating Div Bug found while in edit mode

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, footer

I found a bug while editing a post. There is a floating div to the right of the page. During "edit" mode this floating div becomes "fixed" after you scroll down so much on the page. The problem is that it continues to float even onto the footer of the page. Screen shot attached.

[image]

Comment: See [Right-hand sidebar covers the footer on the “ask question” page and markdown help page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel)